# About Second Shifting Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Given equation:

$$y''+y=h(t)$$

initial conditions, $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$

where h(t+2$\pi$)=h(t)=$1$, if 0$\leq$t$\leq$$\pi$ or $0$, if $\pi$< t< 2$\pi$

Should I use Laplace Transform t-shifting to solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Laplace transform formula for periiodic functions[Laplace transform formula for periiodic functions](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laplace_Transform_of_Periodic_Function).

Your function is:
$$f(t)=u(t)-u(t-\pi)$$
Take the Laplace Transform of $f(t)$:
$$F(s)=\dfrac 1s- \dfrac {e^{-\pi s}} s$$
So that Laplace transform of $h(t)$ is:
$$H(s)=\left (\dfrac 1s- \dfrac {e^{-\pi s}} s \right)\dfrac {1}{1-e^{-2\pi s}}$$
$$H(s)=\dfrac 1 s\left ( \dfrac {1-e^{-\pi s}} {1-e^{-2\pi s}} \right)$$
The original equation:
$$y''+y=h(t)$$
Becomes:
$$Y(s)(s^2+1)-s=\dfrac 1 s\left ( \dfrac {1-e^{-\pi s}} {1-e^{-2\pi s}} \right)$$

Comment: How did you calculate $\frac{1}{1-e^-2(\pi)s}$?

Comment: Thats the formula for periodic function @santi Since you have a peridoic function of $2\pi$

Comment: What does the condition of $1$ or $0$ tell me in the question?

Comment: Now I should do left side as $S^2Y(s)-sf(0)-f'(0)+Y(S)$ right?

Comment: Yes @santi I added some lines  $y'(0)$ and $y(0)$ not $f(0)$

Comment: I added a  link for the formula in my answer @Santi

Comment: Now I should make the equation as $Y(s)=$ right?

Comment: Yes exactly @Santi

Comment: Then I should do inverse Laplace transform for $\frac{1}{s}(\frac{1-e^-\pi s}{1-e^-2\pi s}+s)*\frac{1}{s^2+1}$?

Comment: Exactly @Santi  ....inverse la place transform